# I can´t add publish_to_groups permissions to my app

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm having a problem, I can´t add the permission publish_to_groups to my app, on functions it says ready to use, but when I try to add it to the token, it's not showing in the options. My app is live, but I can´t add on group permissions, the account used is the owner of the app and the group.

I have other app with same permissions and it shows there, what more I have to do?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue. I was able to fix it by creating a new app. On the first step of app creation, Facebook asks you to select the type of app you are creating. The options are Consumer, Business, Game, etc. I had originally selected "Business" because the description says "Create or manage assets like Pages, *Groups*, ...". Once you make your selection, it restricts the types of permissions, products, and more that your app has access to. For some reason, even thought I had advanced access to the Groups API and the `publish_to_groups` permission, I could not add it to my scope requests.

So, on the step where you select your type of app, choose "None" instead. I was able to create a new app and instantly was able to see the `publish_to_groups` permission on the explorer tool and posted to a group right away.

Comment: hi! there's no "none" option there...

Answer (score 0):

Based on their docs publish_to_groups is being deprecated. Maybe the reason it is not in the list anymore.

see: https://developers.secure.facebook.com/docs/permissions/#p

**publish_to_groups**

*Deprecated for v19.0. Will be removed for all version April 22, 2024.*

The publish_to_groups permission allows your app to post content into a Group on behalf of a person if they've granted your app access.
Allowed Usage
Allow people to publish content from your app to their Facebook group.
Help people manage the content published to their group.